# How to prevent Android Studio from turning tabs into spaces when moving into one?

Tags: android-studio, tabs, whitespace, space

If I write

```
TabTab
```

I want it to stay as

```
TabTab
```

However, if I'm at the start of the code of the line, such as

```
TabTab[CursorHere]Code
```

and I move left with the arrows, it turns into

```
SpaceSpaceSpaceSpaceSpaceSpaceSpace[CursorHere]SpaceCode
```

when it should be

```
Tab[CursorHere]TabCode
```

How to fix this?

If I wanted fine alignment I would, logically, write

```
TabSpaceSpaceSpaceSpaceCode
```

I tried unchecking everything but this problem remains.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community Hello, Community Bot, I don't think I can make it more specific.